# The Class-Path manifest attribute in path referenced one or more files that do not exist

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

Trying to use jersey in springboot 2 and getting the below error.

> The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\joannes.paul.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2\2.5.0-b42\hk2-2.5.0-b42.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/hk2-utils.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/javax.annotation-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/javax.inject.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/hk2-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/aopalliance-repackaged.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/config-types.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/hk2-core.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/hk2-config.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/tiger-types.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/hibernate-validator.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/validation-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/jboss-logging.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/classmate.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/hk2-locator.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/javax.inject.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/javassist.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/hk2-runlevel.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/class-model.jar,file:/C:/Users/joannes.paul/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/asm-all-repackaged.jar

dependencies in pom.xml

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-b63</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish-hk2/issues/462#issuecomment-512267293 Currently I had to downalod them manually and rename them removing the version...